# Position of words within pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to count how many times a word appears in a certain position within a column.
For example:

```
Text
    Manchester United, finally, won ...
    Arsenal is one of the best ...
    Beckham played for Manchester United
    Manchester is a city in the UK
```

and so on

I think I should apply something like this, but rather than char I should consider words:

```
max_len = max(map(len, sequences))
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0]*max_len)  # d[char] = [pos0, pos12, ...]
for seq in sequences:
    for i, char in enumerate(seq): 
        d[char][i] += 1
```

I would like to get information about positions of the word Manchester within that text, if possible.

Comment: ``df.Text.str.find("Manchester")``. It will return a `-1` if 'Manchester is not found in the row

Comment: Thanks sammywemmy. So 0 would be at the first position, then 1 at the second and so on? To select a subset where the word is at the first position, how should I do?

Comment: yes; however, reading your question again, this solution might not be what you want, as it returns position via characters, instead of words. so for row 2, it would return position 19, counting characters, instead of 4, if you are counting words

Comment: I see. I would need to take into account words position (not character position of that word)

Comment: Try this : ``[
    ent.index("Manchester") if "Manchester" in ent else None
    for ent in df.Text.str.split()
]``

Comment: yes, it works, thanks. How can I create a column, something that can be related to each text (for a better readability)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this list comprehension:

```
df["position"] = [ent.index("Manchester") 
                 if "Manchester" in ent else -1
                 for ent in df.Text.str.split()]

df

         Text                               position
0   Manchester United, finally, won ...      0
1   Arsenal is one of the best ...          -1
2   Beckham played for Manchester United     3
3   Manchester is a city in the UK           0
```

Comment: I do not know why in this way I get all -1 values. Using the code in the comment was working fine

Comment: running in a jupyter notebook? maybe restart notebook, or change -1 to None (shouldn't be an issue though)

Comment: Yes. I restarted but it still the same (all -1). So weird. I think the problem is in the assignment